# How do I make check a file name, and if it exists, then to add a counter thingy

Tags: php

I'm stupid, please help me.
I'm not sure why this wouldn't work
I want it to check if a file exists. If it does, then add a count thing.
Something like, if "file" exists. add (2).
Output: file (2). and if "file (2)" exists, change the 2 to a 3, and so on and so forth.

```
if (file_exists($receverfs)) {
                $dupe = "2";
                $dupesubject = "$subject ($dupe)";
                while (file_exists($dupesubject)) {
                    $dupesum = $dupe + 1;
                    $dupesubject = "$subject ($dupesum)";
                    echo $dupesubject;
                
            }
            } else {
                $dupesubject = $subject;
                echo $dupesubject;
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had to do work with making unique filenames in the past and found using a `do/while` to be the easiest way to approach this problem:

```
<?php

$original_file = 'test.txt';
$original_subject = 'test';

$file = $original_file;
$subject = $original_subject;

$pathinfo = pathinfo($original_file);

$dupe = 1;
do {
    if ($dupe > 1) {
        $file = $pathinfo['filename'] . ' (' . $dupe . ').' . $pathinfo['extension'];
        $subject = $original_subject . ' (' . $dupe . ')';
    }
    ++$dupe;
} while (file_exists($file));

echo $subject . PHP_EOL;
```

In my directory, I have test.txt and test (2).txt. After the loop, the output of `$subject` will be "test (3)"